# find first empty column and write there vertical

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill a worksheet from a userform, i need to fill a column with data and then the next transaction will go in the column next to that.

https://i.ibb.co/HhNQmTS/Capture.jpg

When i debug.print my formula i can see indeed the last column, but it keeps overwriting it selfs.

```
Private Sub casa()
Dim lColumn As Long
Dim sh As Worksheet
lColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Debug.Print
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(1).Value2 = TXTFECHA.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(2).Value2 = TXTIMPORTE.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(3).Value2 = TXTSUMCOM.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(4).Value2 = TXTSUBTOTAL.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(5).Value2 = TXTSUMIVA.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(6).Value2 = TXTSUMFACT.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(7).Value2 = TXTSUMCOM2.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(8).Value2 = TXTRETORNO.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(9).Value2 = TXTREMANTE1.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(10).Value2 = TXTSUMCOSTO.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(11).Value2 = TXTREMANTE2.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(12).Value2 = TXTCOSTOINTERNO.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(13).Value2 = TXTREMANTE3.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(15).Value2 = TXTSUMComisionista1.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(16).Value2 = TXTSUMComisionista2.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(17).Value2 = TXTSUMCOM3.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(18).Value2 = TXTSUMYT.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(19).Value2 = TXTSUMComisionista3.Value
Sheet47.Range("test").Cells(20).Value2 = TXTSUMComisionista4.Value
End Sub
```

How can i make this happen??

Comment: You're not using `lcolumn` at all.

Comment: I found my problem and now it is working  Set sh = Worksheets("Tu Casa Express")
lColumn = sh.Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1
Debug.Print lColumn
sh.Cells(lColumn)(3).Value2 = CMBCLIENT.Value